# Why I receive a type error?

Tags: python

My code below:

```
class Fraction:
"""Class for performing fraction arithmetic.
Each Fraction has two attributes: a numerator, n and a deconominator, d.
Both must be integer and the deonominator cannot be zero."""

def __init__(self, n , d):
    """Performs error checking and standardises to ensure denominator is positive"""
    if type(n)!=int or type(d)!=int:
        raise TypeError("n and d must be integers")
    if d==0:
        raise ValueError("d must be positive")
    elif d<0:
        self.n = -n
        self.d = -d
    else:
        self.n = n
        self.d = d

def __str__(self):
    """Gives string representation of Fraction (so we can use print)"""
    return(str(self.n) + "/" + str(self.d))

def __add__(self, otherFrac):
    """Produces new Fraction for the sum of two Fractions"""
    newN = self.n*otherFrac.d + self.d*otherFrac.n
    newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
    return(newFrac)

def __sub__(self, otherFrac):
    """Produces new Fraction for the difference between two Fractions"""        
    newN = self.n*otherFrac.d - self.d*otherFrac.n
    newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
    return(newFrac)

def __mul__(self, otherFrac):
    """Produces new Fraction for the product of two Fractions"""        
    newN = self.n*otherFrac.n
    newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
    return(newFrac)

def __truediv__(self, otherFrac):
    """Produces new Fraction for the quotient of two Fractions"""        
    newN = self.n*otherFrac.d
    newD = self.d*otherFrac.n
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
    return(newFrac)

def __eq__(self, otherFrac):
    return(self.n * otherFrac.d) == (self.d * otherFrac.n)

def gcd(self):
    gcd = 1
    if self.n % self.d == 0:
        return self.d
    for k in range(int(self.d / 2), 0, -1):
        if self.n % k == 0 and self.d % k == 0:
            gcd = k
            break
    return gcd

def simFrac(self):
    newN = self.n / f.gcd()
    newD = self.d / f.gcd()
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
    return (newFrac)
```

When I try to run the progress of simFrac() there is an error coming out from the system.

This is my test:

```
f=Fraction(30,18)
f.gcd()
6 #The output of f.gcd()
```

And we I try to type f.simFrac()

it come out with a error look like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    f.simFrac()
  File "C:/Users/Kavan/Documents/Python/resit CE/Q4.py", line 67, in simFrac
    newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
  File "C:/Users/Kavan/Documents/Python/resit CE/Q4.py", line 9, in __init__
    raise TypeError("n and d must be integers")
TypeError: n and d must be integers
```

I know there is an error about the integer from the fuction(simFrac), but I not sure how to solve it, can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: `/`-ing two ints always produces a float. `//` produces an int (flooring if the exact result has nonzero fractional part).

Comment: I don't think this is directly related to your problem, but you're supposed to use `isinstance` for type checking, not `type`.

Comment: i'm using python 3.5.2

Comment: in python 3  `/` always produce a float, use `//` instead

Comment: Is not work , its come out a message of "<__main__.Fraction object at 0x0350ECD0>"

Comment: that is because you don't implemented a `__repr__` method

Comment: @ChristianDean he did, but that is only called when you call print or str on it

Comment: @Copperfield I meant to say `__repr__`.

Comment: Thx guys, is work